# React is forgetting select value on multi step form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

and so I faced with a problem. I'm using react-form-hook with material-ui to create multi step form. the problem is when I stem forward react-form-hook forgets select value. the select component:

```
const Second_step_component = ({ register, errors }) => {
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
    

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setAge(event.target.value);
    };


    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} error={Boolean(errors.Age)}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Age</InputLabel>
            
            <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                value={age}
                label="Age"
                {...register("Age", {required: "Age Is Required"})}
                onChange={handleChange}
            >

                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            <FormHelperText>{errors.Age?.message}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
    );
}
export default Second_step_component
```

I understand that it's reverts back to its default state of '', but when its seems my knowledge is to limited to change useState to register("Age"), if someone could give me some hints, I would be very grateful

also including main stepper component:

```
const steps = ['House', 'Materials'];

export default function HorizontalLinearStepper() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}, trigger} = useForm()
  const [state, setstate] = useState([{}]);


  const isStepOptional = (step) => {
    return step === 1;
  };

  const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
    return skipped.has(step);
  };

  const handlesub = (data) =>{
    setstate(data)
    console.log(data)
  }
  const handleNext = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let isNext = false
    
    switch(activeStep){
      case 0: isNext = await trigger(["Miestas", "Getvė", "Numeris"]);
      break;
      case 1: isNext = await trigger(["Age"]);
      break;
    }
    if(isNext){
      setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    }

  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleSkip = () => {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
      // You probably want to guard against something like this,
      // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
      throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  };


  let Swithing = null
  switch (activeStep) {
    case 0:
      Swithing = <First_step_component register={register} errors={errors}/>
      break

    case 1:
      Swithing = <Second_step_component register={register} errors={errors}/>
      break
    
  }

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{padding: "2rem", display: "grid", placeContent: "center"}}>
    <Box sx={{ width: '500px' }}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            labelProps.optional = (
              <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>
            );
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
      {activeStep === steps.length ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>
            All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
            <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
          </Box>
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>

       
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>Step {activeStep + 1}</Typography>
          <form id='step-form-sub' onSubmit={handleSubmit(handlesub)}>
            <Box>{Swithing}</Box>
          </form>
          
          


          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
            <Button
              color="inherit"
              disabled={activeStep === 0}
              onClick={handleBack}
              sx={{ mr: 1 }}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
            <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
            {/* {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
              <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleSkip} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                Skip
              </Button>
            )} */}

            {activeStep === steps.length - 1?
            (<Button form="step-form-sub" type='submit'>submit</Button>)
            :
            (<Button type='button' onClick={handleNext}>next</Button>)
            }

            
          </Box>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just by reading the question and not the code or details, I can come up with two possible problems:
A - You are not using controlled forms.
B - You are un-rendering the components so you lose the state value on each consecutive step.
Solution to A  would be to save the date the user enters in `state` and provide it to the form components via their respective `value` attributes.
Solution to B would  be to create a state wrapper (provider if you will) which wraps around the X steps and provides a getState (or state variable) and setState functions.

Comment: as I understand value should be saved in register("age") from react-form-hook, because if I use <TextField> component everything save perfectly between steps

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox ?

Comment: Don't replace/unmount form tree conditionally, You will loose the ```state``` attached to those component and RHF will re-initiate the things. Go with ```display: none``` on steppers.

Comment: @MallikarjunMG Common practice is to actually have a common parent / container which holds the state of the children if they need to mount and unmount.

Comment: @Dimitar Yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way you architected your stepper.

The state in the second step will be reverted to the original value once it's unmounted.

The solution is to move the state Into the wrapper component (e.g. if your wrapper component is App.jsx => move all stepper states into it)

Please have a look at the following stepper on code pen to understand:

[React stepper](https://codepen.io/AdamMorsi/pen/qBRazPM?editors=0010)

```
const App = () => {
    const [acceptFirstTerms, setAcceptFirstTerms] = useState({
            checked: false,
            touched: false,
        }),
        [acceptSecondTerms, setAcceptSecondTerms] = useState({
            checked: false,
            touched: false,
        }),
        [acceptThirdTerms, setAcceptThirdTerms] = useState({
            checked: false,
            touched: false,
        }),
        [isSecondStepLoading, setIsSecondStepLoading] = useState(false);

    const firstTermsHandler = () => {
        setAcceptFirstTerms((prev) => ({ checked: !prev.checked, touched: true }));
    };

    const secondTermsHandler = () => {
        setAcceptSecondTerms((prev) => ({ checked: !prev.checked, touched: true }));
    };

    const thirdTermsHandler = () => {
        setAcceptThirdTerms((prev) => ({ checked: !prev.checked, touched: true }));
    };

    //for demo purposes only
    const timeout = (ms) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    };

    const secondStepAsyncFunc = async () => {
        //it can be an API call
        setIsSecondStepLoading(true);
        await timeout(3000);
        setIsSecondStepLoading(false);
        console.log('second step clicked');
    };

    const stepperContent = [
        {
            label: 'Step 1',
            content: (
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={acceptFirstTerms.checked}
                            onChange={firstTermsHandler}
                        />{' '}
                        Accept first terms and conditions
                    </label>
                </div>
            ),
            isError: !acceptFirstTerms.checked && acceptFirstTerms.touched,
            isComplete: acceptFirstTerms.checked,
        },
        {
            label: 'Step 2',
            content: (
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={acceptSecondTerms.checked}
                            onChange={secondTermsHandler}
                        />{' '}
                        Accept second terms and conditions
                    </label>
                </div>
            ),
            clicked: () => secondStepAsyncFunc(),
            isLoading: isSecondStepLoading,
            isError: !acceptSecondTerms.checked && acceptSecondTerms.touched,
            isComplete: acceptSecondTerms.checked,
        },
        {
            label: 'Step 3',
            content: (
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={acceptThirdTerms.checked}
                            onChange={thirdTermsHandler}
                        />{' '}
                        Accept third terms and conditions
                    </label>
                </div>
            ),
            isError: !acceptThirdTerms.checked && acceptThirdTerms.touched,
            isComplete: acceptThirdTerms.checked,
        },
    ];

    const submitStepper = () => {
        console.log('submitted');
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h2>Default stepper</h2>
            <Stepper stepperContent={stepperContent} submitStepper={submitStepper} />
            <hr />
            <h2>Inline stepper</h2>
            <Stepper stepperContent={stepperContent} submitStepper={submitStepper} isInline />
            <hr />
            <h2>Vertical stepper</h2>
            <Stepper stepperContent={stepperContent} submitStepper={submitStepper} isVertical />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I don't use individual states im using react-form-hook, which does the same in essence. this handleChange state is totally unnecessary for me, it was in material ui. I will change my question to include main component